# Close was called before test could end safely using EndTest when running the test in multiple threads

Tags: java, testng, extentreports

I am getting below `ExtentTestInterruptedException` exception when I am running my test in **multiple threads**(Using TestNG to launch test in multiple threads):

```
com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTestInterruptedException: 
Close was called before test could end safely using EndTest.
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.terminate(Report.java:425)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.close(ExtentReports.java:917)
```

Steps Followed

1. I am starting my test in `@BeforeTest` method with extent report `startTest` method
2. And ending my test with extent report `endTest` in `@AfterMethod` method
3. My extent report close method is defined in `@AfterSuite` function.
4. I removed `close()` method call from `@AfterSuite` but in that case result for few of the test cases appears as unknown.

Can someone please help me in resolving this query?

Comment: Please share trial code.

Comment: import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;

import java.io.File;

public class ExtentReport
{
    public static ExtentReports extent;
    public static ExtentTest test;

    public static void initExtentReport() {
        extent = new ExtentReports(
                System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/test-output" + File.separator + "API.html",
                true);
        extent.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/reportconfig.xml"));
    }
}

Comment: Include trial code in your question only. You need to share your code of AfterMethod and AfterSuite annotations.

Comment: @NikhilIndurkar I would recommend using version 4 API.  Version 2 is no longer support and version 3 is also nearing end of support.  Docs: http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/

Comment: @foursyth: I integrated with 4.05 version of aventstack extent report and I am not getting the same error message also but in this case the pass test case does not have any information i.e when I see the result the pass test case have no log information (Somehow I am not able to add attachment to this issue)

Comment: It would be helpful to analyze if share your usage. There are a few changes in version 4 coming from 2.

Comment: BeforeSuite
    public void setUp(){
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("./New.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }
BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeMethod(Method method) {
        test = extent.createTest( this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " :: " + method.getName());
    }
  Test(dataProvider = "invoiceServiceData", groups = {"Sanity"}, threadPoolSize = 5, invocationCount = 10)
    test...
    AfterSuite
    public void tearDown(){
        extent.flush();
    }

Answer (score 1):

This is related to extent report. I'm not sure how you write your @after method but only what i can guess is you use `reports.endTest(test);` in your code. **This is in older version of extent report**. Most probably your problem is with it. Here is an **alternative** with latest extent report solution since no extent report related code for your problem is available in here.

```
@AfterMethod
public synchronized void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {

    StringBuilder inputArgs = new StringBuilder();
    Object objects[] = result.getParameters();

    for(Object obj : objects){
        if(obj==null){
            inputArgs.append("  ");
        }else{
            inputArgs.append(obj.toString());
        }
        inputArgs.append(" , ");
    }

    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
        test.get().fail(result.getThrowable()+ "Input Parameters : "+inputArgs.toString());
    else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
        test.get().skip(result.getThrowable() + "Input Parameters : "+inputArgs.toString());
    else
        test.get().pass( " Test Passed. Input parameters : " +inputArgs.toString());
    extent.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When test fails, if it is not handled for the extend.endTest() you will face this issue.
I have used the below ITestListener method to handle the test failure. Here the reason is captured and logged to the report and end the extent report logging.

```
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult t)
    {
        if(t.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            String reason = t.getThrowable().toString();
            logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, reason);
            extent.endTest(logger);
        }

    }
```